# Aggregating columns in df A by information in df B

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe A, containing the fatty acid amounts (as colums) in plant pollen (species as rows) like this: [note that both are just madeup examples]

| species_ID | Butyric | Caprylic | Succinic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AcMi | 0.01 | 0 | 2 |
| BaVu | 0.002 | 5.2 | 1.4 |

and a dataframe B with the same fatty acids in rows and additional information in columns:

| substance | class | carbons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Butyric | saturated | 2 |
| Caprylic | unsaturated | 5 |
| Succinic | saturated | 5 |

Now I want to do my code like this:
Match the columnname of dataframe A to the rownames in dataframe B, then aggregate the data of the columns of dataframe A by the information of a given column in dataframe B.
Or more clear: I want to merge columns of df A based on the background information provided by df B, e. g. based on the class so it ends like this:

| species_ID | saturated | unsaturated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AcMi | 2.01 | 0 |
| BaVu | 1.402 | 5.2 |

What I tried was this:

```
aggregate_by_factor <- function(data_fa, background_fa) {
  acids_columns <- colnames(data_fa)[-1]
    matching_info <- merge(
      data.frame(substance=acids_columns),
      background_fa,
      by="substance"
    )
  aggregated_data <- aggregate(. ~ class, data=data_fa[,c("species_ID", acids_columns)], sum)
  return(aggregated_data)
}

result <- aggregate_by_factor(data_fa, background_fa)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in aggregate(. ~ class, data = data_fa[, c("species_ID", acids_columns)],  : 
  unused argument (data = data_fa[, c("species_ID", acids_columns)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 <- read_table("species_ID  Butyric Caprylic    Succinic
AcMi    0.01    0   2
BaVu    0.002   5.2 1.4")

df_2 <- read_table("substance   class   carbons
Butyric saturated   2
Caprylic    unsaturated 5
Succinic    saturated   5")

df_1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(!1, names_to = "substance") %>% 
  left_join(df_2) %>% 
  summarise(across(value, sum), .by = c(species_ID, class)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = class)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  species_ID saturated unsaturated
  <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1 AcMi            2.01         0  
2 BaVu            1.40         5.2
```

Comment: values_from = value is unnecessary, it's the default value

Comment: also across is doing not much here, as you're just using it with one column

Comment: @Mark Sure, `across()` is somewhat abundant, but the alternative is to write `value` twice. Just a preference on my end. Thanks for the input on `values_from`

Comment: 1. the word you are looking for is redundant, not abundant, 2. the alternative is `value = sum(value)`

Answer (score 0):

One problem in `aggregate` is that the formula refers to "class", but there is no column in `data_fa` called "class". Even if `matching_info` was used, I think this could be simplified further.

If you wish to use base R, first, you can put your `data_fa` data.frame into long format and then merge with the second data.frame. Then, you can `aggregate` and sum the `values` for each `species_ID` and `class` combination.

Finally, if the desired output is in wide form, you can use `reshape` here. If there are additional columns of related information, you can also include those as well.

```
cbind(data_fa[1], stack(data_fa[-1])) |>
  merge(background_fa, by.x = "ind", by.y = "substance") |>
  aggregate(values ~ species_ID + class, FUN = sum) |>
  reshape(direction = "wide", idvar = "species_ID", timevar = "class")
```

**Output**

```
  species_ID values.saturated values.unsaturated
1       AcMi            2.010                0.0
2       BaVu            1.402                5.2
```